# Storing EAX register in a variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I am currently working on a bonus assignment for a class in which we have to rip out a keygen from an executable and use the __asm directive in C++ to straight insert the assembly code (with a little editing).

The result is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char userName[] = "USERNAME";
    int serNum;

    __asm {

        LEA edx, [userName];              //put user name in edx

        LEA eax, DWORD PTR[edx];          //put user name in eax
        LEA ebx, DWORD PTR[userName + 1]; // put "sername" in ebx
        MOV ecx, 0x00000000;              // random initializing
        MOV ebp, 0x00000000;
        MOV esi, 0x00000000;
        MOV edi, 0x00000000;

    COUNT_loop:;

        MOV CL, BYTE PTR DS : [eax];     // code to get length of user name
        INC eax;
        TEST CL, CL;
        JNZ SHORT COUNT_loop;

        SUB eax, ebx;
        MOV ebx, eax;
        SAR ebx, 1;
        MOVSX ebp, BYTE PTR DS : [ebx + edx];
        IMUL ebp, ebp, 0x3E8;
        XOR eax, eax;

        CMP ebx, 2;
        JL SHORT SKIP_jump;

        MOV edi, edi;

    GEN_loop:;

        MOVSX ecx, BYTE PTR DS : [edx + eax];        //generate the key somehow
        LEA ecx, DWORD PTR DS : [ecx + ecx * 4];
        LEA esi, DWORD PTR DS : [esi + ecx * 2];
        MOVSX ecx, BYTE PTR DS : [edx + eax + 1];
        LEA ecx, DWORD PTR DS : [ecx + ecx * 4];
        LEA edi, DWORD PTR DS : [edi + ecx * 2];
        ADD eax, 2;
        LEA ecx, DWORD PTR DS : [ebx - 1];
        CMP eax, ecx;
        JL SHORT GEN_loop;

    SKIP_jump:;

        CMP eax, ebx;
        JGE SHORT ODD_skip;
        MOVSX eax, BYTE PTR DS : [eax + edx];
        LEA edx, DWORD PTR DS : [eax + eax * 4];
        LEA ebp, DWORD PTR SS : [ebp + edx * 2];

    ODD_skip:;

        LEA eax, DWORD PTR DS : [edi + esi];
        ADD eax, ebp;                                  // store final key in eax
    };
}
```

The problem is that I need the contents of EAX now. I am not sure how to store EAX in another variable. Any ideas? I have never worked with assembly and I was told I wouldn't have to know how to use it. I think they lied to us....

Comment: I don't know much low level stuff myself, but from the readings I've done, `EAX` is used to store return values for functions called with the cdecl convention. If you can turn that block of asm into a function, through I don't know, linking? Function pointers? You could probably work. Again, I don't know for sure, but I have a feeling you can do that somehow

Comment: Inline asm is a feature of your compiler, not of the C++ language itself.  What compiler are you using?  And what OS is this meant to run on?

Comment: @NateEldredge `DWORD PTR` and use of `__asm {` would suggest he is using _MASM_ (or a MASM compatible assembler) inlined in an MS C++ program. I'm guessing the target is a Win32 application, but I agree that such information would be beneficial in the question.

Comment: You have bigger problems. Since your assembly modifies `ebp`, you won't be able to access frame variables any more.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio on Windows 10 as Michael deduced. Thanks for the info on the `ebp`, @Raymond - can I just use a substitute in a different register instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common function calling convention for x86 is cdecl, where a function's integral return value is saved in the EAX register. For example, a simple assembly function can be:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int f()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, 42 // setting EAX to 42 here
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = f();
    printf("%i\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

What you have appears to be Intel syntax, so you might want to compile that inline assembly with the `-masm=intel` flag.

Compiling with Visual Studio on Windows 10 64 bit, and running the executable will produce in the terminal:

```
42
```

The original `f()` will be functionally equivalent to (as far as I can tell):

```
int f()
{
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: The OP's code is not gcc.  Also, assuming that putting a value in eax is going to result it it being returned might work sometimes, but is not explicitly supported.  Consider: What happens if f() gets inlined?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd sorry, just saw OP's comment. Changed to MSVC. Still works. I actually have no idea what would happen if a function with inline asm gets inlined. I tried marking `f()` as inline, but it didn't change anything, for this case at least. My guess is that it'd depend on how the asm is processed by the compiler, but I have no idea how MSVC does it. This is my first time writing x86, as well as interfacing with C/C++ code, and I'm just surprised my example worked at all. I'll see if I can dig anything up later on. I need to study for exams. If anybody knows anything let me know

Comment: `inline` means nothing about codegen, does MSVC have something similar to `__attribute__((always_inline))`? GCC-style register constraints are *so* much nicer ...

Comment: Also, inline only applies if optimizations are enabled.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd @o11c yep. I put it on `/Ox`, and `__forceinline` appears to be the `__attribute__((always_inline))` on MSVC

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I tried using a function and it throws an error because I'm corrupting the data around the `userName` stack. However, once I take care of that, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare an int (or unsigned int) in the C part of your program, and then do

mov cvariable, eax

in the in-line assembler block.